# Balance bench grinder weight distribution

Tags: hardware

This is my bench grinder on a piece of foam cushion that blocks around 70% of the vibration reaching the carpet.

Because of the weight difference between a grinding wheel and the brush wheel, it leans a little to the right.

I do not want to add a grinder wheel to the left side.

I thought about suspended a weight from the left side to counter balance it.

Any ideas strike your fancy?

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Screw the grinder onto a much wider piece of plywood. Place that plywood onto an equally-wide piece of foam. That will distribute the weight a lot more widely, and place less weight on any one section of the foam, so it will rest at a much more level angle.

[image: grinder with modified base]

It would probably also work to extend the base *just* to the right, instead of to both sides.

Comment: I solved it by putting a wedge of foam under the left side. My level was also used

Comment: @fixit7 Well that's pretty simple! Good solution.

Comment: My fix did not last. Am getting bigger piece of foam. :-)

Comment: @fixit7 I hope that works! My thinking is that if one side of the grinder is heavier, it's _always_ going to compress that side of the foam more. Therefore, if you can spread out the grinder's weight across a wide board, then the pressure on the foam will be even, and therefore the foam will get compressed evenly.

Answer (score 0):

If I see correctly in the picture, the grinder is fixed to the table with two screws.

My hints:

1. apply more tension to one of the screws, until the grinder gets tot he desired position;
2. add some rubber / foam between the screws and the grinder, to further reduce vibrations.

Comment: It's not fixed, only free floating on the foam.